# Chrome DevTools: Close Lighthouse-Report

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

I'm not sure if this is the right location to ask...

I am frequently using Chrome DevTools for debugging. Now I saw that there was a new tab "Lighthouse" and I started to generate a report.

It turned my Webpage into a mobile view. When I close DevTools it resets but every time I restart my Chrome DevTools it automatically turns the Webpage into mobile view.

How do I stop this lighthouse report while still using DevTools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is about using software (so should probably be on superuser.com) it is an easy one to answer so I will answer then vote to close the question.

In the very top left of the developer tools window you will see two icons. The second icon is for mobile emulation, the one located right next to the "Elements" tab.

On your screen this will be blue as you have it activated, simply click this to remove mobile device emulation.

[image: Location of mobile view top left]

On Lighthouse itself if you want to test the Desktop version of the site you will see some options before you run the report, you will see "Device" and two radio buttons, just change it to "Desktop"

[image: location of Device setting on Lighthouse]

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the answer and the tip for superuser.com

Comment: Not an issue, glad you are all sorted as that must have been annoying! hehe.

Comment: You can't imagine ;) 
Always had to close the DevTools right up to the moment I wanted to use them. Really helpful... :)